# Drag-drop not working for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on VMware® Workstation 15 Pro

Tags: vmware, 20.04, drag-and-drop

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on VMware® Workstation 15 Pro Version 15.5.2 build-15785246. The problem is that the drag and drop feature (From the host (Windows 10) to the guest (Ubuntu) on the VMware) doesn't work. I've tries the following two methods, but no success!

Method (1):

1. `sudo apt-get autoremove open-vm-tools`
2. Install VMware Tools by following the usual method (*Virtual Machine --> Reinstall VMware Tools*)
3. Reboot the VM
4. `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools`
5. `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop`
6. Reboot the VM

Method (2):

1. Go into VM / Settings / Options / Guest Isolation
2. Uncheck both checkboxes (*Enable drag and drop, Enable copy and paste*) and click OK.
3. Shut down the guest, and shut down VMware Workstation
4. Reboot the host computer
5. Run VMware Workstation but do not launch the guest yet.
6. Go into VM / Settings / Options / Guest Isolation for the guest, and
7. CHECK both checkboxes
8. Power On the guest.

Any idea how to solve the issue, please?

Comment: From the host (Windows 10) to the guest (Ubuntu) on the VMware

Answer (score 5):

Enter the following command in terminal to enable drag and drop between virtual machines and the host.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false
```

Do the following to enable drag and drop between two virtual machines:

1. Open the virtual machine settings editor (VM > Settings), click the Options tab and select Guest isolation.
2. Select Disable drag and drop to and from this virtual machine to disable the feature. Deselect it to enable the feature.

Comment: I did this too, but nothing changed unfortunately! :(

Comment: Try this: `apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop`. This may help.

Comment: Run this: `sudo  /usr/lib/vmware-tools/bin32/vmware-user-loader &`

Comment: Errors regarding permission turned up and I added "sudo" at the beginning of the commands. Still nothing different!

Comment: I've done this already. Please refer to the method (2) to the question body.

Comment: You need to uncheck the guest isolation box.

Comment: Which box? Drag and drop or copy and paste? There are two boxes!

Comment: Drag and drop should be unchecked.

Comment: It's not even showing the drag shadow now either!

Comment: Try reinstalling vmware. That may help sometimes.

Comment: You can try virtualbox. That definitely works.

Comment: The first command is not useful for Ubuntu **20.04** as Nautilus doesn't handle desktop items anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Go to this path, so you can find your draged files

```
/var/run/vmblock-fuse/blockdir/
```

for "View" you drag file full path to the terminal window

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same problem where copy and paste stopped working with Workstation Pro 15.5.7 on Win 10 with Ubuntu 20.04 guest. Was working fine until both guest and host had some updates so hard to tell what caused it.  The simple fix was a variation from method 2 from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236606).

1. Shut down the guest
2. Go into VM / Settings / Options / Guest Isolation
3. Uncheck both checkboxes (Enable drag and drop, Enable copy and paste) and click OK.
   Note: that it is not possible to uncheck these boxes unless the VM is stopped
4. Shut down VMware Workstation
5. Start VMware Workstation.
   Note: there was no need to reboot host
6. For the VM in question, go into VM / Settings / Options / Guest Isolation
7. Check both checkboxes (Enable drag and drop, Enable copy and paste) and click OK
8. Start the guest VM

Copy and paste now works again in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

That issue appeared again and is resolved in Workstation 16.2.3 Pro Version.
Here are the release notes:

```
Resolved Issues

    Cannot copy and paste on a guest virtual machine from a host machine

    In VMware Workstation 16.2.1 Pro, when you try to copy and paste from the host machine to the guest virtual machine, the Paste option in the Edit menu is unavailable.
```

See:
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.2.3/rn/vmware-workstation-pro-1623-release-notes/index.html